# Integer representation of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

What is the integer representation of pointer?

> A pointer value is a safely-derived pointer to a dynamic object only
>   if it has an object pointer type and it is one of the following:
>
> [...]
>
> — the result of a reinterpret_cast of an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer value;
>
> [...]

My doubt is about the following:
Type `int` is less than any pointer to type. In particular, pointer to cannot be casted to int using `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: "Type `int` is less than any pointer to type." I'm not entirely sure what that means, but I'm pretty sure it's incorrect. The relative sizes of `int` and pointer types are not specified; it's entirely possible for `int` to be the same size as, or even wider than, a pointer type (and not all pointer types are necessarily the same size). Not that it matters, though, since the quoted text refers to *integers*, not specifically to `int` (which is just one of several integer types).

Answer (score 3):

The term is defined in the very next paragraph of the standard.

> An integer value is an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer only if its type is at least as large as
>   `std::intptr_t` and it is one of the following:
>
> — the result of a `reinterpret_cast` of a safely-derived pointer value;
>
> — the result of a valid conversion of an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer value;
>
> — the value of an object whose value was copied from a traceable pointer object, where at the time of
>   the copy the source object contained an integer representation of a safely-derived pointer value;
>
> — the result of an additive or bitwise operation, one of whose operands is an integer representation of a
>   safely-derived pointer value `P`, if that result converted by `reinterpret_cast<void*>` would compare
>   equal to a safely-derived pointer computable from `reinterpret_cast<void*>(P)`.